# Display only 1 row in unioned query where they have rows certain criteria in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I couldn't think of a better title to this thread but I have the below Unioned query that is pulling in exam information per UserID that is unioned to pull in the total of the counts.

The problem is that when the UserID has two rows in PS_JOB AND one row has a PER_ORG value of 'CWR' and the other row has a PER_ORG value of 'EMP' then the query is returning 2 rows for this same UserID. In this scenario I only want to display the 'EMP' record, so that only 1 instance of their ID (that falls into this scenario) will count in my Totals (ZTOTAL).

I imagine I need some sort of WHERE condition with NOT EXISTS where it finds two rows with the same UserID, **AND** one row contains PER_ORG = 'EMP' and the other row contains PER_ORG = 'CWR', but am struggling as to how to code this. I don't want to exclude USERID's that have two rows in PS_JOB with any other combination of values for PER_ORG, other than 'EMP' and 'CWR'.

**Current SQL:**

```
SELECT 
    A.USERID, 
    A.IMMUN_CODE, 
    B.COMPANY, 
    COUNT(*) AS 'COUNT_OF_EXAMS'
FROM 
    PS_HS_IMMUN A,
    PS_JOB B,
    PS_EMPLMT_SRCH_QRY B1 
WHERE 
    (B.USERID = B1.USERID 
    AND B.EMPL_RCD = B1.EMPL_RCD 
    AND B1.OPRID = 'GG125' 
    AND (   A.USERID = B.USERID 
            AND B.EFFDT =   (SELECT MAX(B_ED.EFFDT)
                             FROM PS_JOB B_ED 
                             WHERE B.USERID = B_ED.USERID 
                             AND B.EMPL_RCD = B_ED.EMPL_RCD 
                             AND B_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) 
            AND B.EFFSEQ =  (SELECT MAX(B_ES.EFFSEQ) 
                             FROM PS_JOB B_ES 
                             WHERE B.USERID = B_ES.USERID 
                             AND B.EMPL_RCD = B_ES.EMPL_RCD 
                             AND B.EFFDT = B_ES.EFFDT)
        )
    ) 
   AND A.HISTORY_ONLY <> 'Y' 
GROUP BY  A.USERID, A.IMMUN_CODE,  B.COMPANY 

UNION 

SELECT 
    'ZTOTAL', 
    '', 
    '', 
    COUNT ( D.USERID) 
FROM 
    (PS_HS_IMMUN D 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (PS_JOB E 
        INNER JOIN PS_EMPLMT_SRCH_QRY E1 ON 
        (E.USERID = E1.USERID 
         AND E.EMPL_RCD = E1.EMPL_RCD 
         AND  E1.OPRID = 'GG125' )) ON  
    D.USERID = E.USERID) 

WHERE 
    (
        (E.EFFDT =      (SELECT MAX(E_ED.EFFDT) 
                        FROM PS_JOB E_ED 
                        WHERE E.USERID = E_ED.USERID 
                        AND E.EMPL_RCD = E_ED.EMPL_RCD 
                        AND E_ED.EFFDT <= SUBSTRING(CONVERT(CHAR,GETDATE(),121), 1, 10)) 
        AND E.EFFSEQ = (SELECT MAX(E_ES.EFFSEQ) 
                        FROM PS_JOB E_ES 
                        WHERE E.USERID = E_ES.USERID 
                        AND E.EMPL_RCD = E_ES.EMPL_RCD 
                        AND E.EFFDT = E_ES.EFFDT) 
     --AND D.EXAM_DT BETWEEN :1 AND :2 
     --AND E.COMPANY = :3 
        AND D.HISTORY_ONLY <> 'Y' )
    )
```

**Current Results From Above Query:**

[image]

In this example, the two rows for UserID 4992 is duplicated because the UserID has two rows in the PS_JOBS table, hence why the USERID displays twice (and ultimately counts twice in the totals) in the query.

If I do a query from PS_JOBS for this USERID, you will see the two rows for this USERID **AND** the PER_ORG status of 'EMP' and 'CWR', respectfully.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM PS_JOB
 WHERE EMPLID = '4992'
```

**Results from above query:**

[image]

I'm looking to avoid using Common Table Expressions as a solution. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You can use top 1 in SELECT and add predicate PER_ORG = 'EMP"

Comment: @Aurelian  What do you mean exactly?

Comment: There will be instances where an USERID could have a single row in PS_JOB with PER_ORG value of 'CWR', I still want to be able to capture these in the date. It's just where the same USERID has a row for PER_ORG = 'EMP' and another row with PER_ORG = 'CWR'

Comment: I tried the following, however it doesn't retrieve back any data:                      
                                                                                                        AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PS_GHS_HS_IMMUN BB
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_JOB BBBB ON BB.EMPLID = BBBB.EMPLID AND BBBB.PER_ORG = 'CWR')
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PS_GHS_HS_IMMUN 
              BB
    LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_JOB BBBB ON BB.EMPLID = 
           BBBB.EMPLID AND BBBB.PER_ORG = 'EMP'))

Comment: You are using old-style joins. [You should really start using explicit joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). It makes these types of things far easier. Then, you could use a derived table or windows function.